# How to return invalid form fields back to the page?

Tags: node.js, express

It's a classic case of create and edit a form data. I got a complex form that suppose to render back all fields to validate it, but doesn't works. For this case, I've created a simple example to illustrate my concern and try to understand what's happing.

In this sample app **body parser** and **method override** are up:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

Now I have a simple form in **user.jade**:

```
doctype 5
html
    header
        title Add new user
    body
        h4 User - Add
        form(id='userForm', method='post', action='/user/save')
            label(for='name') Name
            input(type='text', id='name', name='name')
            label(for='address') Address
            input(type='text', id='address', name='address')
            input(type='submit', value='Save')
```

The **GET** and **POST** HTTP Methods are configured:

```
app.get('/user/new', user.create); //create new user
app.post('/user/save', user.save); //save or edit user in validation process
```

Finally the **"create"** and **"edit/save"** functions:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    res.render('user');
};

exports.save = function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var address = req.body.address;

    //do some validation
    //...

    //return it back to page to fix wrong fields
    res.render('user', { name: name, address: address });
};
```

Why I render user.jade back, so the fields are not filled? Can't use res.render to fill page form?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In user.jade you aren't using #{name} or #{address}

try something like this to access the local variable

```
        input(type='text', id='name', name='name', value=#{name})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to specify in new user name and address as empty strings. So I have to do: `res.render('user', { name: '', address: ''});` in create function and chage jade as you mentioned, but I see no other way. Btw Thanks!!

Comment: np. Jade also has if statements. So you could test for the local variables and use a different <input> tag for either case instead of always passing in empty strings